# Use threads only for web service call and not for Db call

Tags: c#, multithreading, web-services, sublist

My app in c# is working this way. I start as many threads as it is value in config file (dynamic creation of threads). What every thread is doing is: it goes to DB, calls stored procedure (if I have 60 threads, there are deadlocks). After that, every thread is calling web service, and going back to update rows. Here is how it is looking like

```
List<Message> messages =getMessages(ThreadNO);//goes to DB

if (messages != null)
{
    foreach (Message bm in messages)
    {
        if (bm.Status)
        {
            try
            {
                bm.send();//calls Web service
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LOG.Logger.Error(ex.ToString());
            }
            updateStatus(bm);//goes back to DB
        }
        else
        {
            if (bm.subscribe())
                updateSubscription(bm);//calls WS
            else
                updateUnsuccessfulSubscription(bm);//calls WS
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to do this in a DB less expensive way. I would like only once to go to DB, and after that to create sublists from object messages. After that I will create as many threads as sublists, and those sublists I will pass to send() method. Each thread will call send() method. But when I finish everything, how can I get out of threads and only once call stored procedure to update (updateMessage() method)?
How can I do this in a way to only **use threads only to call web service**, and at same time to **call Db out of threads**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question completely, but if you want to restrict the database calls to one at a time, you can just use a `lock:`

```
// put this field in a class somewhere
static object gate = new object();

// then wrap all your database calls in locks:
lock( gate )
{
  updateStatus(bm);
}
```

That way, it doesn't matter how many threads try to call the database concurrently, only one call will be able to run at a time.

Comment: He wants to batch them such that there is only one query (in total), not just one at a time.

Comment: That is a good idea, but I would like to avoid locks, because there are are other apps runing on server, and with this lock i would lock entire table, whic is used by at least dozen apps. My question is is there any way make this scenario: 1.call Db to get messages;2.start threads and call web service (for about 60 threads);3.after all threads finished, I start foreach and update all messages (go back to Db)

Comment: The 'lock' here, isn't on the table, the program checks for a lock on the object 'gate'

Comment: @Servy yes that is correct. I would like to make linear 3-step procedure, where 2nd step is parallel.

Comment: @Nicholas Butler how this lock should be used? Is it better to use it 'lock (gate)
{
conn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
}' or in a procedure that calls this method that goes to db 'lock (gate)
{
getmessages();
}'?

Comment: @DukaNikolau yes - that's fine. Only one thread at a time can enter the lock region, so your database access will be serialized.

Comment: @DukaNikolau There's an excellent ( and free ) ebook here: [Albahari](http://www.albahari.com/threading/). It explains how locking works in .NET.

Comment: Thank you. I have solved problem with lock statement, but not temporary. I still have DB entrance as many as there are threads. I think that best solution will be to split app on two apps. One app will do getting messages, and write data to txt files. Second app will read txt files and send those data to web service. it will also delete txt file that have been readen. After that, first app will go to DB to update statuses for each message.

Answer (score 2):

I think [`Parallel.ForEach()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx) would be useful in your case.

What you would do is to get the list from the DB, then process the items in parallel using `Parallel.ForEach()` and when it completes, finally update the database.

Something like:

```
var messages = GetAllMessages(); //goes to DB

Parallel.ForEach(
    messages,
    new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = threadCount },
    message => { /* your code that calls the web service */ });

UpdateAll(messages); // goes back to the DB
```

`Parallel.ForEach()` does not guarantee that `threadCount` threads will be used, but in your case, you are likely to get to that number quite soon, because calling the webservice blocks.

Comment: I can have 1000 messages, and this would make 1000 calls to web service. Better way is to make sublist from messages list and in each list to put 10 messages (create 100 threads, because 1000 is to much for web service)

Comment: @DukaNikolau I didn't see anything in your code that would indicate that you can do that. But even if you have 1000 messages, `Parallel.ForEach()` won't create 1000 threads.

Comment: TPL optimises the number of threads to use, based on the machine its running on. And the Threadpool configuration settings.

Comment: @svick this sound like a good idea, but I am not able to use Parallel class. I forgot to mention that my app is on.NET 3.5, and Parallel is available after .NET 4.

Comment: @DukaNikolau Then I think you should consider upgrading, .Net 4.0 is now 3 years old.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the consumer/producer pattern, see for instance http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem

Your initialization will access the DB and start the producers (each a separate thread). These will call the web service and record the status in a shared in-memory data structure (the queue).

A single consumer (thread) will look for elements in the shared queue and, save them in the DB and remove the from the queue.

Comment: Producer-consumer is useful when the producer works (relatively) slowly for a long time, but that's not the case here. Instead all items are produced at once.

Answer (score 0):

Do your select first, on a single thread

Then use threading to go through collection of Messages( I would use [Parallel.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537608.aspx), it takes so much hassle out of rolling your own threads)

Now your select is out the way you can do the updates, but even in a single thread you can still get a deadlock with someother task, your code should expect and handle it.

Comment: I can not use Parallel, because my app is on .NET 3.5